# Iterate Two Ranges In For Loop

Tags: python

I have a couple of simple loops like so:

```
for i in range (30, 52):

    #do some stuff here

for i in range (1, 18):

    #do some more stuff
```

What I would like to is condense this into one loop using syntax of the order:

```
for i in range((30, 52), (1, 18):

    #do some stuff
```

I realise that syntax will not work, but that is the basic concept of what I need. I've seen people using zip to iterate two ranges simultaneously, but this is not what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chain them using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary hi, thanks for replying. you couldn't elaborate on the syntax could you? thanks.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think `product` is what OP is looking for?

Comment: @Kasra They have separate loops, not nested one, so...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yeah,it seems so!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain :

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
> it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
> iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
> single sequence.

Example:

```
import itertools as it
for i in it.chain(range(30, 52), range(1, 18)):
    print(i)
```

for python 3

you can loop into the two ranges together

Example:

```
import itertools as it
for i, x in it.zip_longest(range(30, 52), range(1, 18)):
    print(i, x)
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks a lot. will accept in 8 mins!

Comment: Just a note: "itertools" can offer better performance as it provides optimized C implementations of several common functions that can be faster than their pure Python equivalents.

Answer (score 9):

You can convert the two iterators for your ranges to lists and then combine them with an addition:

```py
for i in list(range(30, 52)) + list(range(1, 18)):
    # something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in zip(range(30, 52), range(1, 18)):
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(30, 52) + range(1, 18):
    #something
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It seems that `+` operand is not allowed between `range`.